# Sheafification construction - Liu's book

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I am doing an exercise in Qing Liu's *Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves* on an alternative definition of the sheafification of a presheaf but can't see why the gluing property holds.

More precisely, let $\mathcal{F}$ be a presheaf (of rings say) on a topological space $X$. Fix a cover $\mathcal{U}=\{U_i\}$ of $X$ then we get a complex $$0 \rightarrow \mathcal{F}(X) \overset{d_0}\rightarrow \prod\limits_i\mathcal{F}(U_i) \overset{d_1}\rightarrow \prod\limits_{i,j} \mathcal{F}(U_{ij}),$$ where $U_{ij} =U_i \cap U_j$, $d_0(s)=(s|_{U_i})_i$ and $d_1((s_i)_i)=(s_i|_{U_{ij}}-s_j|_{U_{ij}})_{i,j}$.

Define $\mathcal{F}_{\mathcal{U}}(X)=\ker d_1$ and extend to all open sets $V \subset X$ with the cover $\{U_i \cap V\}$ to define the presheaf $\mathcal{F}_{\mathcal{U}}$.

By refining our cover of $X$, we get a directed set and define $\mathcal{F}'(V)= \lim\limits_{\rightarrow} \mathcal{F}_{\mathcal{U}}(V)$ to be the direct limit across the covers.

I want to show that this is actually a sheaf but can't seem to verify the gluing axiom. I know that this should actually be the sheafification and all the stalks are therefore equal but I don't see how to use this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Let $\mathcal{U}$ be a cover. What does it mean for $\mathcal{F}'$ to satisfy the sheaf codition w.r.t. $\mathcal{U}$? Now notice that you ran over all possible covers in the construction of $\mathcal{F}'$

Comment: Sheafification is not a *direct* limit, it is an *inverse* limit. Naturally you can extend the maps $\mathcal{F}(U_i)\times \mathcal{F}(U_j)\xrightarrow{p_1} \mathcal{F}(U_i)\xrightarrow{\rho^i_{ij}}\mathcal{F}(U_{ij})$ and $\mathcal{F}(U_i)\times \mathcal{F}(U_j)\xrightarrow{p_2} \mathcal{F}(U_j)\xrightarrow{\rho^j_{ij}}\mathcal{F}(U_{ij})$ to two maps $\prod_i \mathcal{F}(U_i)\to \prod_{i,j}\mathcal{F}(U_{ij})$. Then sheafification is the equalizer of these two maps.

Comment: @SaalHardali do you mean to imply that $\mathcal{F}_{\mathcal{U}}$ is a sheaf? If I take a set of sections of $\mathcal{F}'(U_i)$ which agree on overlaps, must there be some cover where the gluing happens? (This feels like it should be in the definition of limit somewhere but I'm not sure).

Comment: No. What i'm saying is $\mathcal{F}_{\mathcal{U}}$ satisfies the sheaf condition w.r.t. $\mathcal{U}$. Now try to see how you can elevate this to a proof.

Comment: @SaalHardali I'm not sure what you mean by satisfying the sheaf conditions with respect to a cover. Can you please elaborate?